# Adding Navigation Controller

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, uistoryboard

I am trying to follow the directions in the "App Development in Swift" book from apple. The current exercise requires me to add a navigation controller to a series of view controllers.
Originally, the storyboard looks like this
[image]

According to the book, selecting the red view controller and adding a navigation controller should automatically add a navigation bar to all related views. The project should look like this:
[image]

However, the navigation bar does not appear on all my views. Mine looks as follows:
[image]

As you can see, the navigation bar only appears on the red view controller. Any ideas what I might have done wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:** just realised what your actual problem is. The segue between your red and yellow view controllers is the "Present Modally" type, which means it will not use the navigation controller.

It looks like you want to use the "Show (e.g. Push)" segue type instead, which will use your existing navigation controller. You can change this in the Attributes Inspector for the segue itself (click the arrow pointing from the red to the yellow view controller).

[image: Segue Type]

---

**Original answer:**

Take a look at the Simulated Metrics for the yellow view controller, in the Attributes inspector. You might have set the "Top Bar" setting to "None". Try setting it back to "Inferred", which is the default.[image: Inferred Metrics view]